# Using activerecord-postgis-adapter and point is not cast as spherical

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, rubygems, postgis, rgeo

I'm trying to create a basic app using the activerecord-postgis-adapter gem and am following the instructions in the readme.

According to the readme, a point is supposed to use the spherical factory, but I get a CAPIPointImpl type instead of a SphericalPointImpl for a point.  This means that a distance calculation doesn't work.

Here is what I am trying:

```
record = MySpatialTable.create
record.lonlat = 'POINT(-122 47)'
record.lonlat
returns #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl:0x3ff57d7645c8 "POINT (-122.0 47.0)">
```

I am using ruby 2.3.1, rails 5, postgres 9.6 and postgis 2.3

This is my schema:

```
 create_table "my_spatial_tables", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.geography "lonlat",       limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}

    t.index ["lonlat"], name: "index_my_spatial_tables_on_lonlat", using: :gist
  end
```

My initialization:

```
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
  config.default = RGeo::Geos.factory_generator
  config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "point")
end
```

And my database config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  schema_search_path: public, postgis
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by explicitly creating a spherical factory and creating the point from it - so

```
 geofactory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
 MySpatialTable.lonlat = geofactory.point(user.longitude, user.latitude)
```

It does seem like there is a bug, either in the activerecord-postgis-adapter gem or the rgeo-activerecord gem.   I couldn't figure the bug out though.  The SpatialFactoryStore looked like it was setup correctly, but it just wasn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a bug in activerecord-postgis-adapter. Only solution i found - set spherical factory as default factory in initializer:

```
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
  config.default = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
  config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "point")
end
```

This works for me.